# DataBinding DataSet to GridView yields infinite loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to bind a GridView to a DataSet, but it throws a Stack overflow error. When I debug it, it runs to the DataBind line just fine (it seems like its getting the right records from the server and everything), but after executing the DataBind, it jumps to the top of the method and reruns the entire method, which results in an stack overflow.

I can't understand why this isn't working. I've done something very similar with a DataTable before and it worked fine.

Here is how I'm binding

```
    public void CreateGrid(String str)
    {
    try
    {
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MY_CONNECTION_STRING"].ConnectionString;
        sqlConnection.Open();
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(str, sqlConnection);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().Name + ":" + ex.Message);
    }
    if (dt.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        Grid.DataSource = dt;
        Grid.DataBind();
    }
    }
```

And here is my HTML part

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
 OnDataBinding="RebindGrid" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="5" 
 OnPageIndexChanging="Grid_PageIndexChanging"
 OnSorting="Grid_Sorting"
 Width="100%" CssClass="mGrid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" ItemStyle-Width="0%" 
            HeaderText=""  Visible="false" SortExpression="ID"/> 
    </Columns>  
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What does your RebindGrid() method look like? There's a good chance it's calling your method again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem

```
OnDataBinding="RebindGrid"
```

Every time data is bound, you rebind. We would have to see the code for RebindGrid.

Comment: Correct. Very dumb mistake on my part. I removed a line earlier that was preventing it from databinding again in the Rebind method. Completely forgot. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the `RebindGrid` method actually does but it looks like your rebinding your grid as your binding it.

Remove `OnDataBinding="RebindGrid"`.